# How do you redirect to an actionresult from a custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

My MVC webpage currently authenticates using a Session variable. I wanted to try and make it so I can use a custom AuthorizeAttribute so I am able to decorate controllers with [CustomAuth].

Currently the RedirectToRouteResult is taking me to a "this page cannot be displayed" page. The code is hitting the first RedirectToRouteResult.

It does the same if I use RedirectResult

How to I get it to direct to the login page I have?

This is my customAuth

```
 public class CustomAuth : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["isAuth"] != null)
        {
            if (!(bool)filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["isAuth"])
            {

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new 
                    RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Base", action = "Login" }));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new
                RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Base", action = "Login" }));
        }
    }
}
```

Edit---

I want to use [customAuth] on controllers and actions instead of having to put this in every action in every controller

```
 if (Session["isAuth"] != null)
        {
            if (!(bool)Session["isAuth"])
            {
                Session.Clear();
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Base");
            }
        }
        else return RedirectToAction("Login", "Base");
```

Is there a way to do that with Anonymous Authentication?

Comment: What is the path to your login page?

Comment: base/Login, if I put _Login for the action it takes me to http://localhost:/Base/_Login with a  resource cannot be found page, which is expected cause there is no _Login. But if I put base/Login it doesn't redirect it just shows a cannot display page page.

Comment: Are you able to navigate to /base/login successfully?  Also, is your controller actually called `BaseController`?

Comment: I am able to and yes it is named BaseController. I can use return RedirectToAction("Login", "Base"); successfully in any of my controller actionresult functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm doing it with an attribute derived from HandleErrorAttribute.

Just assign the filterContent.Result to a new ViewResult to set the destination.  Don't forget the other properties to if you need them.

```
public class HandleUnauthorizedAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() != typeof (SecurityException)) return;

        var controllerName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "Unauthorized",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
}
```

The I just register it in the FilterConfig.cs

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleUnauthorizedAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your controller decorated with [HandleUnauthorizedAttribute] or are you throwing that custom exception???

Comment: What version of mvc are you using?  I added the registration code for mvc 5 to the answer.  This will put the filter on every request.  but if you wanted to, you could put in on the controller or the action.

Comment: I think you are confusing authentication and authorization.  if all you are doing is checking if the user is authenticated you can configure that in the web.config and send unauthenticated users to the login url.